# How can we import own python modules to AWS Lambda layer?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I am attempting to import specific Python files containing functions for reuse. I have zipped all the necessary files and the resulting zip folder structure is as follows:

- utils

  - a.py
  - b.py
  - c.py

After importing the zip as a Lambda layer, I try to import a function from either a.py, b.py, or c.py using `import utils` or `from utils import a, b, c`. However, Python is unable to locate them and I receive a `No modules named utils` error. Can anyone assist me in identifying what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Oh I got where I was doing wrong. It was that I had to copy all the scripts to a folder named python before zipping.

Comment: Was your problem resolved? If so, you are welcome to add your own Answer so that future readers can learn what to do.

Answer (score 0):

As per [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-compile) :

> For each Lambda runtime, the PATH variable includes specific folders in the /opt directory. If you define the same folder structure in your layer .zip file archive, your function code can access the layer content without the need to specify the path.

For Python it's `python` as its path.